# Spring MVC 3.0 Getting Values Out From Sql Query

Tags: java, sql, spring, parameters, resultset

I am newbie in using Spring MVC 3.0. I am writing a custom authentication class and I would like to know how I can extract the values from a SQL query into variables? Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, and some code, which I am asking about, is omitted;

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;

import com.crimetrack.DAO.LoginDAO;
import com.crimetrack.business.Login;

public class JdbcLoginDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport implements LoginDAO {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass()); 
    String dbUserName;
    String dbPassword;

    public boolean AuthenticateUser(Login login) {
        logger.debug("Authenticating User");

        String sql = "SELECT userName, password FROM tblofficers WHERE userName = :userName AND password = :password ";

        //code for parameters : userName and password using login.getPassword() and login.getUsername()
        //and code to get vaules out from query for comparison


        if (dbUserName == login.getUserName()) {

            if (dbPassword == login.getPassword()){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }


    public static class LoginMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Login>{

         public Login mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Login dbLogin = new Login();
                dbLogin.setUserName(rs.getString("userName"));
                dbLogin.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                return dbLogin;
            }       
    }

}
```

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer your question, but if you already have the Spring stack, I'd highly recommend the Spring Security framework. It would manage all your auth/autz problems nicely.

Comment: i was looking at that but here i want to implement a custom login since i want to assign custom functions to users. thanks for the comment its something i was looking at as well much appreciated

Comment: I second Oliviers suggestion, and also doing a plain JDBC query has nothing much to do with spring. Here is an example of how would you accomplish that http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0003 . I would suggest that you don't keep your passwords in db as they are but use some kind of hash function when storing your password in database.

Comment: Well you could do it with Spring Security too. Spring Security provides the framework (session management, URL protection, etc.), but you must still provide the User details, roles and so on through a UserDetails service.

Comment: i am not sure but i am doing some research and i came up with this i dont know if anyone can tell me if i am right :

String dbUserName = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
    sql, new Object[] { login.getUserName() }, String.class);
  
  String dbPassword = (String)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
    sql, new Object[] { login.getPassword() }, String.class);

gets the value from the query and passes the parameters into it as well

Answer (score 2):

Return the query as another instance of your "Login" class using JDBCTemplate and BeanPropertyRowMapper and then compare the objects.

You'll have to look into JDBCTemplate to define the database connection but eventually this would look like:

```
UserLogin authenticLogin = (UserLogin) db_connection.queryForObject(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(UserLogin.class));

if (userLogin.getPassword() == authenticLogin.getPassword()) {
    return true
}
```

Basically, BeanPropertRowMapper will create a new instance of a class settting any properties with the same names as columns returned from the query.